# How to set "IN" values with mysql cpp connector

Tags: c++, mysql-connector

How does one to set the "IN" value for the following SQL statement :

```
UPDATE `test` SET `test`.`status` = 'foo' WHERE `test`.`id` IN (?);
```

Is that possible ? I looked in the headers and couldn't find anything related nor did I find anything in google nor stackoverflow.

Should I use the `setBlob` method ?

Comment: Are you using MySQL C API and looking for method to execute a query for update statement with IN?

Comment: I am using the MySQL C++ API and looking for a method to execute a `PreparedStatement` containing an `IN`.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in MySQL Connector API to handle such case.

But it shouldn't be mind blowing to work it around with a very simple for loop.

- either you loop for each  `id` and update atomically.

```
for each (id in your collection){
    UPDATE `test` SET `test`.`status` = 'foo' WHERE `test`.`id` = (?);
}
```

- or you call a direct statement that you custom-build (also with a `for` loop)...